# How to get image in body in reactJS

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

In back-end, I have an API send an image to body

```
@GetMapping(value = "/image/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getImage(@PathVariable("name") String name) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = newsService.getInputStream(name);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
}
```

I'm just displaying data from a JSON file,  I have never display images from the body. So everyone can help me how to display image I send from back-end. This is my front-end code:

```
const responseImage = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/news/image/${image_name}`, {
        method: "get",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'image/png',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
      })
      const responseData = await responseImage
      this.state.image.push(responseData)
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what backed you are using i am not familier with but you can do is just return  image url of your image which lies in server  to frontend like react you can call api in componentdidmount . Then after you can access easily by <img src={imageurlreturn[enter image description here][1] from server}/>

I hope it is helpful to you ...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1CPV.png